# Creating a DropDownList in Kendo UI using one column as the text field and another column as the data value within the grid

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I currently am trying to create a DropDownList with Kendo UI and would like to use one column of my grid as the text field (what the user sees) and another column as the actual value that DropDownList is returning. Basically I have an ID and a description associated with it that I would like to link together within a DropDownList.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question since it seems pretty simple.

1. The Grids get their data from DataSources.
2. DropDownLists get their values from DataSources.
3. If you use the same DataSource for both... that's it.

Example: We have a DataSource that include a list of Cities with their State and an Id.

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport : {
         read: "url",
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                Id       : { type: 'number' },
                City     : { type: 'string' },
                State:   : { type: 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the Grid we want to show all data but in the DropDownList we just want to show the City and use as value the Id.

What we should do is:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    columns   :
    [
        { field: "Id" },
        { field: "City" },
        { field: "State" },
    ]
});
```

and for the DropDownList we define:

```
$("#ddlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: ds,
    dataTextField: "City",
    dataValueField: "Id"
});
```